# how to make div downstair of one?

Tags: html, css

I had one big problem :/ I want to make one div downstair of first. like that >>
1
2
but I want, they must be center and how to do this? I had JSfiddle demo

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="a">
        (Text A)
    </div>
    <div class="b">
        (Text B)        
    </div>
</div>

.center {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.center .a {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}
.center .b {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

this is demo >> https://jsfiddle.net/3a77qa3o/

Comment: Not sure what you mean, can you clarify?

Comment: Was this what you wanted (https://jsfiddle.net/z2wuy72h/)? I made both child divs position relative. Honestly, I can't tell exactly what you want.

Comment: what do you mean by downstar?

Comment: sorry, I have bad english :'(

Comment: Is this what you want https://jsfiddle.net/3a77qa3o/1/

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/3a77qa3o/3/ @Vatex Official

Comment: Do you have a picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at the below link exactly how you want it to be. **Change position: relative for both the div's**

https://jsfiddle.net/3a77qa3o/2/

```
    .center {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.center .a {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}
.center .b {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: If this is what OP wants, I solved it first in the comments.